# Javascript event issue inside angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I have being doing a simple directive for a HTML form which compare the date selected in two different dropdowns (one for the month and one for the date) with the current date and creates and error in case the date in the form is older than the current. It works almost fine, however, since I am using Javascript´s event "change", when I enter to the dropdowns through the "tab" key, and press the down and up arrow key to change the value inside the dropdown, the event does not fire when I do it for the second time and only when I do it for second time.

Using a different Javascript event didn't really help, and I can not use ngModelController functionality since the directive is inside a div which contains both dropdowns.

Somebody has a clue on how to solve this issue, or knows and alternative way to do the directive?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4191/)

```
app.directive(  'validateExpirationDate', [function() {
    return {
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var select = angular.element(element.find('select'));
            var dateYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            var dateMonth = new Date().getMonth();
            dateMonth += 1;
            var validDate=true;
            function checkDate() {
                alert('I have changed');
                validDate=true;
                if (scope.expMonth != null && scope.expYear != null) {
                    if (dateYear >= scope.expYear && dateMonth > scope.expMonth) {
                        validDate=false;
                    }
                }
                scope.$digest(scope.myForm.month.$setValidity('invalidDate', validDate));
            };
            select.on('change', checkDate);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select (And most other inputs) come with data-ng-change which will fire anytime anything changes. So instead of wiring up your own on change event you can do this:

```
<select name="month" ng-model="expMonth" data-ng-change="checkDate()">
```

And then in your code:

```
           scope.checkDate = function(){
                alert('I have changed');
                validDate=true;
                if (scope.expMonth != null && scope.expYear != null) {
                    if (dateYear >= scope.expYear && dateMonth > scope.expMonth) {
                        validDate=false;
                    }
                }
                scope.myForm.month.$setValidity('invalidDate', validDate)
            };
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78teb/

Comment: thanks, but that didn't solve the problem. In your jsFiddle, in the html section press tab. When the focus is over either of the selects, press down arrow key once, and the alert message will appear, then press it again and it won't appear. That behavior only happens when I press it for the second time. Maybe it could be something related with my machine, i don't know

Comment: Every time I press the down error while focused on one the alert fires.